Значение запятой в предложении с однородными сказуемыми
В приведенном ниже примере, в пункте а, запятая между словом "изделиям 10" и словом "разработала", имеет какое смысловое значение? Значение союза И? Значение союза ИЛИ? Если можно, то не могли бы вы сделать синтаксический разбор этого предложения.

Ежемесячная премия начисляется при выполнении одного из следующих
условий:
а) если мастерская выполнила план продаж по "изделиям 1", "изделиям
2", "изделиям 3" или "изделиям 4" и одновременно план продаж по
"изделиям 10", разработала или утвердила новую категорию изделий до
конца текущего месяца.
б) если общий объем продаж превышает среднемесячное значение в 1,5
раза.

